# Openshift application deployment git

Tags: windows, git, openshift

I am creating openshift application during application creation it will give error mention below....

When I see my open shift account application is created.

```
An exception occurred while creating local git repository.
Clone operation failed, with failed cleanup: Could not delete file C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\y. Manual cleanup may be required.
```

So how i do manual clean up git respository

Answer (score 0):

It's  most likely because that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\y` might already exist and can't automatically be removed. You'll need to remove that file manually.

I'm guessing that you're trying to clone your application into your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\` which I wouldn't recommend since this is the binary folder for GIT. Try running the   `rhc app create` in your home folder `C:\Users\<yourusername` and see if that gives you better results.

Comment: Thanks niharvey.. Its working for me actually, there is problem with SSL public and private key I configure it properly and then I try to clone with another path then its working fine..

Comment: Glad to see its working, go ahead and submit that as an answer and then when you're able to mark it as answered. That way when other user come across this they can see what helped.